# How to merge objects into the right type in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to make a cloudwatch alarm, and I want to either just pass the dimensions as-is into my module, or look up the EC2 instance ID if there is an "InstanceId" dimension to the alarm and use that instead.

I'm doing this in my locals file:

```
  cloudwatch_metric_alarms = {
    for alarm_name, alarm in try(var.cloudwatch_metric_alarms, {}) :
      alarm_name => merge(
      alarm,

      # Add the EC2 instance ID by looking it up from instance name if needed:
      contains(keys(alarm), "dimensions") ? {
        dimensions = {
          for dimension_name, dimension in alarm.dimensions :
            dimension_name => merge(
              { dimension_name = dimension },
              dimension_name == "InstanceId" ? {
                "InstanceId" = local.ec2_instance_lookups[dimension].instance_id
              } : {}
            )
          }
        } : {}
      )
    }
```

However, using merge() to combine the normal dimensions and my edited one means that `dimensions` ends up as an object, and this doesn't seem to be valid input to the aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm resource:

The following definition errors:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "CW-ALARM" {
  for_each = local.cloudwatch_metric_alarms

  # Required for all alarms:
  alarm_name                = each.value.alarm_name
  threshold                 = each.value.threshold
  comparison_operator       = each.value.comparison_operator

  dimensions =  each.value.dimensions
  [...]
```

The error mentions that InstanceId is an element and needs to be a string:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../terraform-cloudwatch-metric-alarms/cw-alarm-main.tf line 9, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "CW-ALARM":
   9:   dimensions =  each.value.dimensions
    |----------------
    | each.value.dimensions is object with 1 attribute "InstanceId"

Inappropriate value for attribute "dimensions": element "InstanceId": string
required.
```

What kind of type should it be, and is merge() the wrong functionality to use here? I am struggling to find good documentation on how to manipulate data structures this way in Terraform and so finding this hard to debug.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: More specifically we cannot assist without the type of `var.cloudwatch_metric_alarms`.

Comment: Alas I am using a convoluted framework I inherited from colleagues past that is auto converting the input variables from JSON so as best I understand it the type definition is just implicit, only variable name and description is specified in variables.tf.

cloudwatch_metric_alarms is an object containing one or multiple objects that each represent an alarm, and each may or may not contain a dimensions object.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce the behaviour I want of this rather complicated nested structure but not yet succeeded, I will update this question if I manage to. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried printing the `local.cloudwatch_metric_alarms` value to see if the `InstanceId` value happens to be something unexpected (like a null)?

Answer (score 0):

This expression seems like it would create an object with an extra level of nesting, like this:

```
{
  InstanceId = {
    InstanceId = "i-example"
  }
}
```

I assume this `dimensions` argument of `aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm` is declared by the provider to be a `map(string)`, and so Terraform is raising this error from trying to convert the object value to that type. That conversion can succeed only if all of the attribute values can convert to strings, but because of the extra level of nesting the nested object cannot convert to a string.

To make this work you'll need to instead generate an object whose attribute values are all strings, like this:

```
{
  InstanceId = "i-example"
}
```

Terraform would then be able to convert that to `map(string)`.

If I'm reading your snippet correctly, it seems that the `merge` here is redundant because the surrounding `for` expression is already visiting each element of `alarm.dimensions` and producing one result element for each input element. I think you could write it as follows instead, to get a result like I showed above:

```
  cloudwatch_metric_alarms = {
    for alarm_name, alarm in try(var.cloudwatch_metric_alarms, {}) :
      alarm_name => merge(
      alarm,

      # Add the EC2 instance ID by looking it up from instance name if needed:
      contains(keys(alarm), "dimensions") ? {
        dimensions = {
          for dimension_name, dimension in alarm.dimensions :
            dimension_name => (
              dimension_name == "InstanceId" ?
              local.ec2_instance_lookups[dimension].instance_id :
              dimension
            )
          }
        } : {}
      )
    }
```

This expression will reproduce the key and value verbatim if the `dimension_name` is anything other than `InstanceId`, but will use the lookup table in the special case for `InstanceId`.